# setting up audio for google assistant on raspberry pi

Tags: usb-audio

I'm following a tutorial for setting up audio for google assistant.  It said to save this script with card and device numbers that I wrote down:

```
pcm.!default {
type asym
capture.pcm "mic"
playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
type plug
slave {
pcm "hw: 1, 0 "
}
}
pcm.speaker {
type plug
slave {
pcm "hw: 0 ,0"
}
}
```

But I'm getting these errors when I do the test commands:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ speaker-test -t wav

speaker-test 1.1.3

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
WAV file(s)
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
Playback open error: -19,No such device

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16000 --
file-type=raw out.raw
ALSA lib conf.c:4886:(parse_args) Parameter DEV must be an integer
ALSA lib conf.c:4991:(snd_config_expand) Parse arguments error: Invalid 
argument
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hw: 1, 0 
arecord: main:788: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

I have USB mini microphone and my speakers are from my hdmi moniter

Answer (score 0):

You can use script from GassistPi project. It have script to configure audio for USB microphone and HDMI audio output.

GassistPi is project that's allow you to create own google assistant device. You can find more info on project page https://github.com/shivasiddharth/GassistPi .

Comment: I think you should give more detailed information to make this a useful answer. What / where is 'GassistPi project' and maybe tell / show what your script does.

Comment: GassistPi is project that's allow you to create own google assistant device. You can find more info on project page https://github.com/shivasiddharth/GassistPi .

Comment: Please update your answer with the additional information

Comment: Done now should be okay.

Comment: I did get it to work after I rebooted.